# Putting enum types in different class

Tags: java, enums

I am making an enum representing different tile types for a tile-based game, and I have a superclass which I want instances of tiles of inherit from. As I just found out, an enum can't extend or inherit from another class!

How can I get around this? My idea was that it might be possible to have the Tile-class be a normal class, and then have the enum in another class. Is this possible to accomplish, or do I need to solve the problem in another way?

Comment: Your proposed solution sounds perfectly reasonable.  Alternately, you might let the different tile types be classes, and use something like the visitor pattern when you need to have different behavior on different tiles.

Comment: you may prefer composition over inheritance in this case.

Comment: The thing that makes inheritance better than composition is that I think it will simplify the collision detection, however, now that you say it, I am not completely sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static fields of a class, for example:

```
class Directions {
    static int LEFT = 0;
    static int DOWN = 1;
    static int RIGHT = 2;
    static int UP = 3;
}
```

Comment: This is a really simply approach, and is the basis of enumerations in most languages. C, for example, has no Booleans so you could implement them in the very same way.

Comment: I can't see what this buys you over an enum.  It loses the type safety, doesn't let you extend another class usefully, and doesn't seem to get you anywhere.

Comment: Yeah I know, however I usually never use static variables/methods so it just didn't occur to me.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote Louis. Safety isn't even a concern this is a matter of preference.

Comment: I can't even inherit from another class in an enum, that is the problem. This is a quick workaround, and I will let JUnit handle the safety concerns. What did you mean by "doesn't let you extend another class usefully"?

Answer (score 0):

You can have any field in enum.

```
public enum YourEnum {
    FIRST(new First()),
    SECOND(new Other()),

    private final Tile tile;   

    private YourEnum(int code, Tile t) {
        this.code = code;
        this.tile = t;
    }

    public Tile getTile() {
        return tile;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would still need static types of Tiles in the Tile class to use this though, is that correct?

Comment: I think you can implement Tile in any internal static or regular public class.